# sum possible to add totals together in a sum?

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure how to explain this but I have this mysql statement -

```
$sql = "
    SELECT SUM(  `invoice_lineitems`.`quantity` )
    FROM  `fd`.`invoices` ,  `fd`.`invoice_lineitems` ,  `fd`.`products`
    WHERE  `invoices`.`source_server_id` =  '" . $server_id . "' AND 
           `invoice_lineitems`.`source_server_id` =  '" . $server_id . "' AND  
           `products`.`source_server_id` =  '" . $server_id . "' AND 
           `invoices`.`invoice_uri` =  `invoice_lineitems`.`invoice_uri` AND  
           `invoice_lineitems`.`lineitem_product` =  `products`.`product_uri` AND
           `invoices`.`creation_datetime` BETWEEN '" . $data[$server_name]["last_year"] . "' AND '" . $data[$server_name]["time_last_year"] . "'  AND
           `products`.`number` =  '21233'";
```

I want to add another number here

```
`products`.`number` =  '21233'";`
```

something like

```
`products`.`number` =  '21233 + 23454'";
```

I can't seem to figure this out.  And No I did not write this code.  I'm trying to see if I can add another product and add both totals.

Comment: Line breaks are allowed in queries and in PHP strings. Wouldn't it be more readable without that huge horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax - and see about (mysqli or PDO and) prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want `in`:

```
 `products`.`number` in ('21233', '23454')
```

Don't use single quotes if `number` is really stored as a number.

Also, you should learn proper, explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  don't use commas in the `from` clause.